# Correct implementation of Autoencoder MSE loss function in TF2/Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, autoencoder

Can someone explain me the difference between the following two please?

Assuming a vanilla Autoencoder with real-valued inputs, according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTU79Zs4XKY&ab_channel=HugoLarochelle) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Rb4s9wNOmc&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=AlfredoCanziani) sources, its loss function should be as follows. In other words a) for each element in an example we calculate the square difference, b) we perform a summation over all elements of the example, and c) we take the mean over all examples.

```
def MSE_custom(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(
        0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(
            tf.square(tf.subtract(y_true, y_pred)),
            axis=1
            )
        )
```

However, in the majority of implementations I see: `autoencoder.compile(loss='mse', ...)`.

I fail to see how the two are the same. Consider this example:

```
y_true = [[0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
y_pred = [[0.0, 0.8, 0.9], [0.5, 0.7, 0.6], [0.8, 0.7, 0.5]]

result1 = MSE_custom(y_true, y_pred)  # 0.355 

mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO)
result2 = mse(y_true, y_pred)  # 0.237
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two differences.

1. The Keras loss *averages* over all dimensions, i.e. your `reduce_sum` should be replaced by `reduce_mean`.
2. The Keras loss does *not* multiply by 0.5.

In your case, you have three dimensions, so we can get to the Keras loss from your result by dividing by 3 (to simulate the averaging) and multiplying by 2. As it turns out, `0.355 * 2/3 == 0.237` (roughly).

These changes might throw you off, but they are ultimately irrelevant because both dividing by N as well as multiplying by 2 are constant factors, and as such only provide a constant factor to the gradients as well.

Edit: The following computation should give you the same result as the Keras loss:

```
mse_custom = tf.reduce_mean((y_true - y_pred)**2)
```

I use overloaded Python operators instead of TF ops for simplicity (subtract/square). This simply averages the entire 2D matrix at once, which is the same as computing an average over axis 1 and then averaging *that* over axis 0.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! If I understood correctly, if I define MSE_custom2 based on your answer:

MSE_custom2(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.square(tf.subtract(y_true, y_pred)),
            axis=1
            )
        )

then having loss=MSE_custom2 or loss='mse' in autoencoder.compile() would be identical and both correct, right?

Comment: Indeed. In fact, you should be able to just use a single `tf.reduce_mean` over all axes (although this kinda "conflates" the difference between averaging over dimensions and averaging over the batch, it gives the same result).

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please? How can I use a single tf.reduce_mean and still get the same result?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Reduction) the MSE is calculated by averaging the squared errors either across the tensor size (`SUM` loss reduction) or across the batch size (`SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE` loss reduction). The code below shows some examples of how you could replicate both MSE calculations.

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = [[0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.8, 0.9, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
y_pred = [[0.0, 0.8, 0.9], [0.5, 0.7, 0.6], [0.8, 0.7, 0.5], [0.9, 0.1, 0.3]]

##############################################
# Loss reduction: "SUM"
##############################################
reduction = tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM

mse_1 = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction=reduction)
print(mse_1(y_true, y_pred))
# tf.Tensor(0.54333335, shape=(), dtype=float32)

def MSE_1(y_true, y_pred):
    x = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(y_true, y_pred)))
    y = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], tf.float32) # divide by the shape of the tensor
    return tf.divide(x, y)

print(MSE_1(y_true, y_pred))
# tf.Tensor(0.54333335, shape=(), dtype=float32)

##############################################
# Loss reduction: "SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE"
##############################################
reduction = tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE

mse_2 = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction=reduction)
print(mse_2(y_true, y_pred))
# tf.Tensor(0.13583334, shape=(), dtype=float32)

def MSE_2(y_true, y_pred):
    x = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(y_true, y_pred)))
    y = tf.cast(tf.multiply(tf.shape(y_true)[0], tf.shape(y_true)[1]), tf.float32) # divide by the size of the tensor
    return tf.divide(x, y)

print(MSE_2(y_true, y_pred))
# tf.Tensor(0.13583334, shape=(), dtype=float32)

##############################################
# Loss reduction: "NONE"
##############################################
reduction = tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE

mse_3 = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction=reduction)
print(mse_3(y_true, y_pred))
# tf.Tensor([0.28333333 0.09666666 0.12666667 0.03666667], shape=(4,), dtype=float32)

def MSE_3(y_true, y_pred):
    x = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(y_true, y_pred)), axis=1)
    y = tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[1], tf.float32) # divide by the shape of the tensor
    return tf.divide(x, y)

print(MSE_3(y_true, y_pred))
# tf.Tensor([0.28333333 0.09666666 0.12666667 0.03666667], shape=(4,), dtype=float32)

# recover "SUM" loss reduction
print(tf.reduce_sum(mse_3(y_true, y_pred)))
# tf.Tensor(0.54333335, shape=(), dtype=float32)

print(tf.reduce_sum(MSE_3(y_true, y_pred)))
# tf.Tensor(0.54333335, shape=(), dtype=float32)

# recover "SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE" loss reduction
print(tf.divide(tf.reduce_sum(mse_3(y_true, y_pred)), tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], tf.float32)))
# tf.Tensor(0.13583334, shape=(), dtype=float32)

print(tf.divide(tf.reduce_sum(MSE_3(y_true, y_pred)), tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true)[0], tf.float32)))
# tf.Tensor(0.13583334, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```